# How to transfer app settings from Galaxy S3 to a S6 without root?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6, data-transfer

After trying to manually set the "app settings" on my new S6 the same as my S3: I realize it will take me hours.  Is there really no way to transfer all old app settings from my S3 to the newly installed apps of my S6?  Helium needs a PC and others need root on both phones.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Reading between the lines: You're looking for a solution to do that directly from device to device with no PC involved? Close to impossible then without root, as no single app can get access to all other apps (or rather their data) without root.

Comment: That "possible duplicate" is quite a bit aged, half of the solutions no longer available, and the other half a bit cumbersome (involving multiple apps for backup/restore). Sure we want to close this on behalf of that one?

Comment: Related (and newer): [Is it possible to migrate apps and their data from one unrooted Android phone to another?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/88563/16575) / [Transfer App data from rooted to unrooted new phone](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/128661/16575)