# Transfer App data from rooted to unrooted new phone

Tags: data-transfer

I got a new (unrooted) Nexus 6P and want to transfer my app data from a rooted Amazon Fire Phone.

Methods I've considered:

- Use titanium backup to backup apps - Can't be restored on my new unrooted phone
- Use titanium backup to create apks that contain app data - Installed apps wouldn't be linked to play store (right?)
- Use google syncing capability? The fire phone doesn't seem to sync the apps even though I have google services installed.
- Use an intermediate rooted device that supports google syncing? Would this actually work? Could I use Bluestacks for this?

I'm open to any other suggestions as well.  The fact that my previous device is rooted seems to help, but I'm not sure how to get around my new device being unrooted since only a system user or each app itself would have permission to rewrite its app data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize the [backup](/questions/tagged/backup) and restore features of [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) for this, as they are available on rooted and not-rooted devices alike – provided they run Android 4+. On the old device: `adb backup -f <appname>.ab -apk <app_package_name>` – on the new device: `adb restore <appname.ab>`. Either do that for each app separately (recommended, as you can "skip some to be dealt with later") – or create a "bundle" by repeating the `<app_package_name>` part in the backup for each app. Package names you can find out via their Playstore URL (`id=<package_name>`).

Some additional details can be found in our [adb tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info) and [backup tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info).

Comment: This didn't actually work for me, but I'm selecting it anyway.  The adb backup function only creates 41 byte files regardless of command using it on the firephone.  Though I think this is the right answer despite the firephone's issue.  But it got me on the right trail. Its just ending up being more manual grabbing the right file from the right apps.

Comment: "The adb backup function only creates 41 byte files regardless of command using it on the firephone." Ah. You've missed my comment in the backup tag wiki: "If your device is rooted, you can work around that using the xposed-framework with the [Backup All Apps](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.pyler.backupallapps) module". A size of 41 byte usually indicates the corresponding app had `ALLOW_BACKUP` set to `FALSE` – that module fixes this.

Answer (score 0):

You can install ZArchiver from Play Store and extract Titanium Backup, then you will see two folders. Extract the "data" folder and install Virtual Backup on a non-rooted mobile and add all those apps which data you want to restore. Add those files into Virtual Backup and take a backup of those files. In this way, you will have a path of, then paste those titanium files and restore.