# How to migrate Android device, including SD card?

Tags: sd-card, 4.3-jelly-bean, 5.1-lollipop, data-transfer, device-migration

I have a Huawei Ascend G6, which uses a 32GB SD card to store most app data. I now bought a Huawei Y6 to migrate to and want to retain as much app data as I can. How would I go about to transfer my apps (data) to the new device?

The Y6 has Lollipop, so when booting the device, I was asked which apps to install. So I got all apps installed now. So how do I go about transferring configuration data? I assume I can't just put my SD card into the Y6 and be done with it?

Comment: Depending on the manufacturer there is some sort of *migration wizard/helper*. As with all Android devices, only system apps have the ability to read/write other apps' data and thus users rely on the availability of a service that has full access. Samsung offers such a helper in the form of *Samsung SmartSwitch*. Maybe Huawei offers something similar. If all fails you need to root both devices and copy/paste all the data manually and fix ownership in the end (only as a last resort)

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to migrate apps and their data from one unrooted Android phone to another?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/88563/16575) Btw, I'm using [adb](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info) for this, via its [backup](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info). Creating separate backups for each app, those can be restored across Android versions and devices.

Comment: @Izzy How would this work with the SD card. I have many apps that have their data partly stored on the SD card. Should the SD card be in the old or new device? Or should I get a second SD card?

Comment: I have never done that (not using App2SD or the likes), but `adb backup` should pick all the data along. If you've got a new card in the new device, leave the old one in the old, do the backup and restore, and see the outcome. Should work IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Helium backup on the older phone in order to make copies of your apps and their settings. These can then be migrated to the new phone through the Helium backup interface. Alternatively, you could take an ADB backup of your old phone and restore it to your new phone. All this is on the assumption that you don't have root?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! This is a question-and-answer site, [not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/192154): please don't add comments as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://android.stackexchange.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, or to add actual comments when seeking clarification of any issues.